# Getting retirement savings back on track after 30

Tags: united-states, 401k, savings, retirement, investing

I've largely ignored dealing with my finances in the past, mostly because I really, really hate dealing with them, and as a result have made some poor decisions. I've been making good money but I've changed jobs a lot. As a result I had multiple 401Ks with some money in them, which I was advised to put into rollover IRA. I did this last year, but because of being clueless about investment, never invested this money. That money has sat, uninvested, for about a year.

Now that I've realized how stupid I've been, I have invested that money. Unfortunately, I also just realized that the maximum annual contribution for this IRA is 5500$ annually. I read that I should be able to contribute up to 18000$ to a 401K annually, but apparently this only applies to employer sponsored 401Ks? I also read that it may be possible to have multiple IRAs?

I realize that I will never get back the growth potential I've missed out on for the last 5 years.
My question is, since I've chosen a path where it makes sense to manage my own retirement savings,

- How should I go about getting back on track?
- Should I look at opening more IRAs and make the maximum contribution annually?
- I also have money in savings that is un-invested, which I was considering using to buy some investments. What is the optimal way it could be put to good use for supplementing the IRA income?

Thanks

Comment: Probably the most important aspect in saving for retirement is the part about **saving** money. It sounds like you have that taken care of, so you are mostly good. You obviously can't go back five years and change history, but you *can* do things differently from this moment on. I would however recommend against dumping a large lump sum into the market; it's almost always better to spread it out a little, to reduce the risk of happening to buy at a local price peak. Yes, the market might climb while you are buying; but it also might fall. Markets are funny like that.

Comment: If you're self-employed, you can open a one-participant 401k.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I would do:

- You've already started by rolling all your 401Ks into a single IRA. If you haven't already, set a target asset allocation for all your investments, and buy index funds within that IRA to match that asset allocation.
- There is no reason to have more than one IRA. Your maximum annual contribution limit for all IRAs is still $5500 total, not $5500 per IRA.
- Make sure to keep enough money in savings to act as an emergency fund. With whatever is left, you can dump $5500/year into your IRA (according to your target asset allocation). If you want to invest the money faster than $5500/year, you can open a regular (taxable) brokerage account and buy index funds there according to the same asset allocation you used above.